# Select2 wont display the initital value set on the django forms

Tags: jquery, django, forms, jquery-select2

I have been working on the select2 and django forms, I would like to display the first object of model to select to I used this code:

```
    class SchoolForm(forms.Form):
        school = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        label=_('Campus'),
        queryset=School.objects.none(),
        required=False,
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.school_sys = kwargs.pop("school")
        super(SchoolForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        school_campus = self.school_sys.school_set.all()

        self.fields['school'].queryset = school_campus

        if school_campus.exists():
           self.fields['school'].initial = school_campus.first()

and spit this to the html however the select2 is showing all school but no initial first value on select2
```

Or just I can do it in on jquery? Thank you